# How to insert in a list in R the variable names of regressors which have pvalue below 5%

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to build a list in R that contains all the regressor names which have pvalue below the 5% threshold.
For example:

first regression

```
#gender (male - female)
regr1 <- lm(salary ~ female, data = test)
summary(regr1)
```

**output first regression:**

```
 Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
 (Intercept)  0.855618   0.001888  453.24   <2e-16 ***
 female      -0.054514   0.003088  -17.65   <2e-16 ***
```

second regression:

```
#education (PhD - Master - Bachelor - HighSchool - None)
regr2 <- lm(salary ~ Master + Bachelor + HighSchool + None, data = test)
summary(regr2)
```

**output second regression:**

```
Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.91008    0.02829  32.164  < 2e-16 ***
Master      -0.05446    0.02836  -1.920 0.054811 .  
Bachelor    -0.10291    0.02848  -3.613 0.000303 ***
HighSchool  -0.10173    0.02911  -3.495 0.000475 ***
None        -0.12590    0.02864  -4.396 1.11e-05 ***
```

The variable master is not significant, so i don't want it in the List.
This is teh list that I would like to get:

```
varnames <- c("female", "Bachelor", "HighSchool", "None")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `broom::tidy` and then manipulate the table, like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

tab <- lm(data = mtcars, mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp) %>% summary() %>% broom::tidy()
tab
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept)  34.2       2.59       13.2  1.54e-13
2 cyl          -1.23      0.797      -1.54 1.35e- 1
3 disp         -0.0188    0.0104     -1.81 8.09e- 2
4 hp           -0.0147    0.0147     -1.00 3.25e- 1
```

Then you filter the `p.value` column:

```
tab %>% filter(p.value < 0.05)
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept)     34.2      2.59      13.2 1.54e-13
```

So now you can take the regressors name:

```
tab %>% filter(p.value < 0.05) %>% select(term) %>% as.character()
[1] "(Intercept)"
```

Answer (score 0):

In base `R` you can do something like the following:

```
lr1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris) 
coef_table <- coef(summary(tab))

row.names(coef_table)[coef_table[, "Pr(>|t|)"] < 0.001]
# "(Intercept)"  "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length"
```